# Google map project is not working on 4.4 versions

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am developing a simple tracking app in android. The app is working fine in android 4.1 version. But when i try to run the app in android 4.4 version devices, the app getting crashes. I don't know why. Please let me any idea to solve my problem. Here with i have attached my code.

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
Location location;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

String currentdatetime_tosend, latitude_tosend, logitude_tosend,
        address_tosend, speed_tosend, username_tosend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        initilizeMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void AddMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String driverName) {
    googleMap.clear();
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(driverName);

    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.driver_car));

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(15).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Double lat = (Double) (location.getLatitude());
    Double lng = (Double) (location.getLongitude());
    speed_tosend = Float.toString(location.getSpeed());
    latitude_tosend = lat.toString();
    logitude_tosend = lng.toString();
    getAddress();
    new SendDetailsInBackground().execute();

}

private void BackgroundProcess() {
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        onLocationChanged(location);
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
    }
};

private void StartTheProcess() {
    BackgroundProcess();
}

private void StopGetingLocation() {
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
    GetLocaion();
}

private void GetLocaion() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    } else {
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Activated",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No location found..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS IS Ennabled..!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        double latitude = (Double) (location.getLatitude());
        double longitude = (Double) (location.getLongitude());

        AddMarker(latitude, longitude, "nani");
    }
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(
            "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                        final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.startGettingLocation) {
        StartTheProcess();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.stopGetingLocation) {
        StopGetingLocation();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}


private void getAddress() {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                Double.parseDouble(latitude_tosend),
                Double.parseDouble(logitude_tosend), 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i) + ",");
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "\n Address==>: " + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();*/
            address_tosend = sb.toString();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address is empty!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Address returned!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is my code. When i try to on the gps the project getting crashed. Please review my code, and let me know why my project getting crashed. The same code is working fine in android 4.1 versions.

```
Target name - Google APIsX86  
Vendor - Google Inc
Platform - 4.4.2
Api Level - 19
```

Please help me to resolve my problem.

My Logcat:

```
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): Process: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, PID: 1710
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.GetLocaion(MainActivity.java:159)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:134)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
11-29 12:45:23.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Use LogCat and see what the cause of your crash is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare.. Thanks for the reply. I don't have own device. And also this project not working on my emulator:-(. So that i can not see the error in logcat :-(..